# Is stateless backend secure?

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, cookies, jwt

I'm developing an application on angular and spring. And I'm a little bit confused on stateless backend being secure. Here's the flow -

1. In request header I send email and pass base64 encoded server returns a cookie which has the jwt token
2. Since it's an http only and secure flag cookie client side has nothing to do with it. On each request to the server it gets attached to the request header.
3. To get deeper knowledge about user activity , I use `mouse-enter`, `mouseleave` functions which post the activity in the db.
4. I'm protecting my app against csrf by sending a client side token

I'm not quite sure if it's secure enough and if I really need to store any token or cookie related data for security.

Comment: I assume you are using SSL ?

Comment: @BertrandMartel Yea i m

Comment: from what i know in JWT, if you want more security you should assure that token is not the same when the user relog (assure rotation), you can use a different secret per user too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People seem to be skeptic on securing stateless backends. For example, the official [Spring Angular guide](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_help_how_is_my_application_going_to_scale) quotes:

> It very definitely is a Good Thing to use the session for authentication and CSRF protection

This presentation by Rob Winch, the project lead of Spring Security, is also a gem to watch: [The State of Securing RESTful APIs with Spring](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/5398-the-state-of-securing-restful-apis-with-spring)

In fact, looking at these, I concluded to remain stateful for my APIs, and not to re-invent the sensitive Security wheel unnecessarily.

Comment: Ok, what I am doing basically is, mimicking the web-client, by sending the JSESSIONID cookie, REMEMBER-ME cookie etc. with each request. The KISS approach.